# How do I access my state inside semantic-ui-react components?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to build a menu using the semantic-ui-react Menu component. But I am unable to use my state inside the Menu.Item component to display individual menu items. How can I use my state inside the Menu.Item

```
class JobTabs extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state={
      tabs: [
        {title: 'Tab 1', index: 0},
        {title: 'Tab 2', index: 1},
        {title: 'Tab 3', index: 2}
      ],

      activeTab: 0
    }

    this.renderTab = this.renderTab.bind(this);
  }

  renderTab(){
    return this.state.tabs.map((tab) => {
      return (
        <Menu.Item
          name={tab.name}
          key={tab.index}
          active={this.state.activetab === tab.index} />
      );
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Menu tabular>
        {this.renderTab()}
      </Menu>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What happened inside `Menu.Item` can't you use `this.state.activetab`?

Comment: Have you checked? There is typo here `this.state.activetab` => `this.state.activeTab`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There was indeed a typo. However I am unable to use tab.name and tab.index. Both them are undefined when I console log them.

Comment: Currently I get a blank active tab without any Menu title

Comment: If I replace tab.name with any string, it ends up as the title. For some reason tab.name is undefined

Comment: `tab.name`  must be `tab.title`. there is no `name` in `tab` object

Comment: Try logging `this.state` in `renderTab()` method

Comment: omg. That is so silly of me. Thanks for the help. It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use title instead name

```
 class JobTabs extends React.Component{

      constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
          tabs: [
            {title: 'Tab 1', index: 0},
            {title: 'Tab 2', index: 1},
            {title: 'Tab 3', index: 2}
          ],

          activeTab: 0
        }

        this.renderTab = this.renderTab.bind(this);
      }

      renderTab(){
        return this.state.tabs.map((tab) => {
          return (
            <Menu.Item
              name={tab.title}
              key={tab.index}
              active={this.state.activeTab === tab.index} />
          );
        })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Menu tabular>
            {this.renderTab()}
          </Menu>
        );
      }
    }
```